# Pass array as an argumento from jQuery to a php handler using $.get and $.param()

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I need to pass an array of numeric values from jQuery to a php file. I fill this array in my code using the following line:

```
Area_Array.push({name: 'A[]', value: ui.value});
```

Then I serialize the array to use it in an URL

```
$.param(Area_Array);
```

I can see that the array is built correctly using:

```
alert(decodeURIComponent($.param(Area_Array)));
```

which returns, for instance, the following:

```
A[]=0&A[]=1&A[]=2
```

that is fine for me, but I don't know now how to insert it inside my $.get which is also sending another parameters:

```
$.get("some.php", { b1 : 0, b2 : 5, b3: 20, b4 : 1},function(foo){});
```

But I want my built URL to have the following structure:

```
http://somehost/some.php?b1=0&b2=5&b3=20&b4=1&A[]=0&A[]=1&A[]=2
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you!!! :)

Alexandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you directly add the values to the array

```
Area_Array.push(ui.value);
```

and then set it as parameter:

```
$.get("some.php", {b1: 0, b2: 5, b3: 20, b4: 1, A: Area_Array},...);
```

There is no need to call `$.param` directly. E.g. the setup above would generate this query string (if `Area_Array` was `[1, 2, 3]`):

```
b1=0&b2=5&b3=20&b4=1&A[]=1&A[]=2&A[]=3
```

jQuery takes care of encoding arrays correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Felix!!! :) I tried it and the resulting URL is "b1=0&b2=5&b3=20&b4=1&A%5B%5D=0&A%5B%5D=1&A%5B%5D=2" do I need to insert a decodeURIcomponent() somewhere?

Comment: @Alexandra: No, PHP (or the webserver) will decode the data automatically. URL encoding is good ;)

Comment: Thank you @Felix! You are the best! Now I will start working on getting the array contents from the php side. Greetings!